# Loadlibrary excatly what #import does?

Tags: c++, winforms

As per my understanding `#import` is taking the required headers/dependencies in compilation time.

`Load library` takes its dependencies in run-time from running pc. If it is wrong please correct me.

Whether `LoadLibrary` exactly what `#import` does?

Comment: #import is used to import COM libraries in VS, so it generates the headers files with the names, GUIDs etc. made available to you (there is a lot of control here) - LoadLibrary doesn't do any of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The #import directive is a **code generator**.  It takes the path to a type library, a language-independent way to describe types exposed by code written in an arbitrary language.  Equivalent to an .h file in C or C++.  Could be a .tlb file, most commonly type libraries are embedded as a resource in an executable file.  The compiler de-compiles the type library content into equivalent C and C++ declarations.

The directive produces two files, you can find them back in your build directory.  The .tlh file is a header file that a C or C++ compiler can use.  The .tli file contains C++ wrapper functions that makes calling the interface methods much less error-prone.  Based on the `_com_ptr_t` smart pointer class that takes care of the required reference counting, the wrapper functions turn error codes into C++ exceptions.

No `LoadLibrary` at all, that's taken care of by the COM infrastructure.  Automatically invoked when you create an object of the exposed type.  CoCreateInstance() is the factory function that takes care of it.  The registry contains the required information to locate the matching executable file.

There is a learning curve, avoid cutting corners.  Lots and lots of books about it, although many are out-of-print today, the MSDN landing page for the C++ wrapper classes [is here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h31ekh7e.aspx).